# What type of image distortion filter is applied?

Tags: image, algorithm, distortion

I have a like-black-box program (compiled code), which generates such images from text.
My goal is to recreate such algorithm in my program. Problem is I need exactly the same algorithm. I tried sin-wave along x-axe, results are quite similar, but really not the same.

Can anybody tells me what image distortion filter is used, and maybe where to read about its algorithm/implementation.
Thanks.

Image with desired results here:

[image: Need such distortion]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In older times I have done this on an Atari ST. The algorithm I used was p(x,y) = p(sin(x)), (sin(y)) but on y-axis you need to add or double the pixels or the lines. This trick makes the special look like a fluid water effect. In fact it was an error and I forgot to delete the pixels in y-axis.

Comment: Thanks. My first experience was with 8086 computers so unfortunately Im not familiar with Atari. But algorithm remains algorithm. Now try and inform You with results, it seems very closely what I looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Its what I looking for. The best fit is p(x,y)=p(x+A1*Sin(a1*y+p1), y+A2Sin(a2*x+p2)), but Your variant is good enouth too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to reverse engineering the exactly same algorithm, because they might just add a little random salt preventing you from that. You might want to get a same-enough algorithm instead of an exactly same one.

If I were you, I will:

1. Treat this algorithm as a **pixel-mapping function**, which means that looks like:

   ```
   New picture        Raw picture
   (0,0)              (0,0)            
   (0,1)              (0,0)
   (0,2)              (1,2)
   (0,3)              (1,3)
   ...                ...
   ```
2. Decide that to which raw pixel a new pixel should map. I would like to just initialize the mapping function by a no-changed function, and then apply a **Monte Carlo based algorithm (like [Genetic Algorithm](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm&ei=tK3NULWEMYOwhAfzh4G4DA&usg=AFQjCNG8g-s8f-aBJy02u44u8HVuTdrvxw&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.ZG4))** to train the function. In each iteration, randomly move or copy a small group of pixels to a neighbor location. Finally you will get an ideal function after enough iterations.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I think algorithm they used is one of common-known image filtering (like photoshop filters shear/twirl/wave). Of course every time I run function with the same text ("example" for exampl :) ) - results are different, so in Your approach after function calucation I will need to investigate what funtion parameters I need to change randomly to achieve desired effects :(